# Haskell: Problems zipping trees

Tags: haskell, tree, ghci

I'm new to Haskell and have been attempting to build a zipping function, that works with Trees that have the following data structure:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show
```

So far I have this:

```
treezip :: (Tree a) -> (Tree b) -> (Tree(a,b))
treezip (Node a leftSubtreea rightSubtreea) (Node b leftSubtreeb rightSubtreeb) =
let l = treezip leftSubtreea leftSubtreeb
    r = treezip rightSubtreea rightSubtreeb
in Node a l r
```

However whenever I try to load the module into GHCi I receive errors, pointing to the last line of code and taking issue particularly the variable `a`.

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out why this wouldn't work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: hint: what should be the value a `Node` stores after zipping?

Comment: A `Node` should store an `Int` value after zipping.

Comment: @J.Doe Where did `Int` come from? `treezip` takes two trees that store arbitrary data, and produces a tree that contains *tuples* of data. If I have a `Tree Char` value and a `Tree Bool` value, I have to produce a `Tree (Char, Bool)` value. So, what should `treezip (Node 'c' Leaf Leaf) (Node 'True' Leaf Leaf)` return?

Comment: Worse, what should `treezip Leaf (Node 'a' Leaf Leaf)` return? Only trees with the same shape can (apparently) be zipped, so the function type should probably be `Tree a -> Tree b -> Maybe (Tree (a, b))`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't work against the compiler, let it help you!

To right a function like that, it's best to start out with only an “outer shell definition”:

```
treeZip (Node a lSa rSa) (Node b lSb rSb) = Node _ _ _
```

The compiler will come back with this:

```
• Found hole: _ :: (a, b)
  Where: ‘a’ is a rigid type variable ...(_bla, bla_)
         ‘b’ is a rigid type variable ....
• In the first argument of ‘Node’, namely ‘_’
  In the expression: Node _ _ _
  In an equation for ‘treeZip’:
      treeZip (Node a lSa rSa) (Node b lSb rSb) = Node _ _ _
• Relevant bindings include
    rSb :: Tree b (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file20584.hs:4:38)
    lSb :: Tree b (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file20584.hs:4:34)
    b :: b (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file20584.hs:4:32)
    rSa :: Tree a (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file20584.hs:4:21)
    lSa :: Tree a (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file20584.hs:4:17)
    a :: a (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file20584.hs:4:15)
```

So, it tells you the first of the `_` *typed holes* should be filled with something of type `(a,b)`. Do we have anything of that type? Well, we can easily build it, namely by taking `a` and `b` and putting them in a tuple!

```
treezip (Node a lSa rSa) (Node b lSb rSb) = Node (a,b) _ _
```

...giving

```
• Found hole: _ :: Tree (a, b)
  Where: ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by...
```

yeah, you've already solved that one – it should be the zip of the sub-trees.

```
treeZip (Node a lSa rSa) (Node b lSb rSb)
     = Node (a,b) (treeZip lSa lSb) (treeZip rSa rSb)
```